# Maven for simple web app (Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, jsf, maven, jsf-2, maven-2

I try to write first maven web app with jsf. And I faced with problem. I try to find the answer.Every deploy I get next stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getPhaseMapForReading(ELFlash.java:736)
    com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.isEmpty(ELFlash.java:465)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:318)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:208)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.debugHtml(DevTools.java:123)
    com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1139)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:249)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:136)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:311)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 logs.
```

My pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"> 
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>by.bsuir.transport</groupId>
    <artifactId>transportApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

What can be the reason of this problem&

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you're having problems with `@FlashScoped` managed bean. Try to not use the bean with this scope and give a try. Next time, don't show your pom or any of those files because it doesn't add any value to the question, the stacktrace and the JSF version and impl it's enough.

Comment: I don't do Maven, but please note that the `com.sun.faces.*` classes are from Mojarra while you've MyFaces in your pom. In other words, you were mixing Mojarra with MyFaces somehow!

Comment: @Luiggi: `@FlashScoped` isn't part of standard JSF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change dependencies and it works

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```